# Sum two text files containing floats row by row in python

Tags: python, text, gzip, sum, text-files

So I have 4,000 large gzipped text files. Because of their size, I need to sum them line by line.  Ideally (I think) I want to open one and then loop through the other 3,999 and simply keep summing their values into the first one. Here is what I have so far

```
with gzip.open('foo1.asc.gz','r') as f:
    for i in xrange(6):  # Header is 6 lines
        f.next()
    line = f.readline()
    foo1=map(float, line.strip().split())
    print foo1
```

This returns the values I need to sum for `foo1`; so output is a comma separated list of floats (e.g., `[1.2, 6.0, 9.3...]`).

So for clarity, if I were to do the same with `foo2 = [1.2, 6.0...]` then I could sum `foo1` and `foo2` to get `[2.4, 12.0...]`, overwriting `foo1`.  Then keep iterating through each line to overwrite `foo1`.  Of course that needs to loop through 4k files.

If anyone can help me with the 2 loops and/or the sum operation I would be greatly appreciative.

* Update ***
Now using the following code:

```
foo1=[]
with gzip.open('foo1','r') as f:
    skip_header()
    for line in f:
        foo1.append([float(i) for i in line.strip().split()])


with gzip.open('foo2','r') as f:
    skip_header()
    for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
        foo1[i] = [j + float(k) for (j, k) in zip(foo1[i], line.strip().split())]
```

which works but is sloooow.  With my inputs about 11 minutes.

Comment: How many floats are in one file?

Comment: Many thousands...Uncompressed text file = 1.3gb

Comment: what is the expected output? For example if both foo1, foo2 files contain `"1 2\n3 4"` then the result is `"2 4\n6 8"` or should it be just `"20"`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian if foo1 and foo2 = [1.0,2.0,3.0] then output should = [2.0,4.0,6.0]

Comment: KennyC: are your files literally use this format `[1.0,2.0,3.0]`? Do not convert to lists. Provide at least two lines as is (imagine what `zcat foo1 | head -2` would show).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian The files are strings, which I convert to lists of floats so I can do the sum calculation

Comment: @KennyC: currently you have: Oz123's answer: *a)* one number per line (is it true for your files?) *b)* the result is an integer: sum of all floats in all files (is it desired output?). Pierre GM's answer: *a)* each line is a row in 2D array *b)* the result is a 2D array: each element is a sum of corresponding elements (the same row, column) from all files. Conclusion: your description of input/output is unclear. Provide specific examples as in my first comment.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian -- Oz123's output does not work for me.  Input files have many floats per line (2D array).  I do not want to sum these floats.  I want to sum line 1 from foo1 with line 1 from foo2 resulting in a float array. So I guess I should be using Pierre GMs answer as you stated?  I want a 2D array of floats that correspond to the sum of elements in line 1 of foo1 and foo2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### In the NORMAL python way...

You are not iterating over the lines...

```
~ $ cat test.txt 
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.5
5.0
6.0
```

you could however read all the lines, and then apply float on them:

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
...      lines = f.readlines()
...      foo1=map(float, lines)
...      print foo1
... 
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.5, 5.0, 6.0]
>>> sum(foo1)
21.5
```

#### however, you should use NumPy!

*crude solution summing all files*

```
import numpy as np

totalsum=0
ListofFiles = ['foo1','foo2']
# from the help of np.loadtxt
# Note that `If the filename extension is .gz or .bz2, the file is first decompressed`
# see the help for that function.
for FileName in ListofFiles:
    totalsum=totalsum+np.sum(np.loadtxt(FileName,skiprows=6))
```

*solution to sum elements from different files*

```
# use with caution it might hog your memory
import numpy as np

totalsum=0
ListofFiles = ['foo1','foo2']

arrayHolder = np.loadtxt(FileName,skiprows=6)
for idx,FileName in enumerate(ListofFiles[1:]):
    arrayHolder=np.hstack((arrayHolder,np.loadtxt(FileName,skiprows=6)))  
# see documentation for numpy.hstack and my example below.

# now you have a huge numpy array. you can do many things on it
# e.g
# sum each file if the above test.txt had an identical file named test1.txt
np.sum(arrayHolder , axis=0)
# output would be:
array([2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 9.0, 10.0, 12.0])
# sum each ith element accross files
np.sum(arrayHolder , axis=1)

# more extended
In [2]: a=np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.5,5.0,6.0])
In [4]: b=np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0,4.5,5.0,6.0]) 
In [9]: c=np.vstack((a,b))  
In [10]: c
Out[10]:
array([[ 1. , 2. , 3. , 4.5, 5. , 6. ],
[ 1. , 2. , 3. , 4.5, 5. , 6. ]])
In [11]: np.sum(c, axis=0)
Out[11]: array([ 2., 4., 6., 9., 10., 12.])
In [12]: np.sum(c, axis=1)
Out[12]: array([ 21.5, 21.5])

# as I said above this could chocke your memory, so do it gradualy, 
# dont try on all 4000 files at once !
```

Note that this solution will run faster for the solution that Pierre offered, since many NumPy function are written and C and are optimized. If you need to run on 4000 line, I expect the for loop to be slower...

Comment: Hi Oz, thanks for your help.  I do desire an optimized solution and numpy would be fun to explore.  But perhaps I should restate my question.  I don't desire the sum of the floats in 1 file.  I need to sum the floats of 2 files together.  foo1 + foo2.  Because of the size of files I'd like to do this line by line

Comment: @KennyC, my solution does give you the sum of `foo1` and `foo2`... just feed the ListOfFiles...

Comment: I see that now but can you provide a numpy solution that sums line 1 from foo1 with line 1 from foo2 resulting in a float array (line 1 of foo3 say). Piere GMs solution did work but took 11 minutes for one sum operation which would take me a month to complete the jobs.

Comment: @KennyC, well. I was being a lazy programmer according to what you wrote. I now extend my answer, and I think Pierre solution IS NOT the way to go, especially if it takes on month to run !

Comment: @KennyC, you can drop the `sir` title (it should be give to Travis Oliphant...). Just out of curiosity, how much faster? you wrote before one cycle took 11 min, so how much time is it with NumPy?

Comment: I saw about a 30% increase in speedup.  Ultimately I sought some help with a C program which can sum two files in about 40seconds.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably have to keep one list in memory, the one storing the lines of your first file.

```
with gzip.open(...) as f:
    skip_header()
    foo1 = [[float(i) for i in line.strip().split()] for line in f]
```

- Note: here, we're building the list at once, meaning that the whole content of `f` is loaded in memory. That can be an issue if the file is large. In that case, just do:

  ```
  foo1 = []
  with gzip.open(...) as f:
      skip_header()
      for line in f:
          foo1.append([float(i) for i in line.strip().split()])
  ```

Then, you could open a second file, loop on its lines and add the values to the corresponding entry of `foo`:

```
with gzip.open(file2) as f:
    skip_header()
    for (i, line) in enumerate(f):
        foo1[i] = [j + float(k) for (j, k) in zip(foo1[i], line.strip().split())]
```

There shouldn't be much problem, unless you have a different number of columns in your files.

If your file are really large, memory can be an issue. In that case, you may want to work by chunks: read only a few hundred lines from the first file and store them in a list, then proceed as described, using as many lines as you read in the first file, then start again for another few hundred lines...

**EDIT**

Given the computation times you describe in the *edit*, this solution is clearly suboptimal. You can't load a whole file in memory, so you'll have to work by chunk. It might be better to follow a workflow as:

1. Create an empty list `foo1`.
2. Open the first file, read a given chunk of lines, transform these lines into a numpy `ndarray` and append this array to `foo1`.
3. Repeat step two for another chunk of lines, till you read the whole input file

At this point, you should have a `foo1` list with as many entries as chunks you defined, each entry being a numpy array. Now

1. Open the second file, read as many lines as you did in step #2, transform these lines into a numpy array `foo2_tmp`
2. Add `foo2_tmp` to `foo_1[0]`, *in place*: that is, do `foo_1[0] += foo2_tmp`. Remember, `foo_1[0]` is your first chunk, a `ndarray`.
3. Repeat step 5. for another chunk of lines, and update the corresponding entry in `foo_1`
4. Repeat step 6. till you read your second file
5. Repeat steps 4.-7. for your third file

Comment: My columns and rows are the same for all inputs.  However, when executing your suggestion I get a memory error on the foo1= line in your first block.  Ideas?

Comment: I have edited OP to show your suggestion.  I am now getting an I/O error

Comment: @KennyC: the `foo1.append(...)` line of the new OP is a bit off, please check it. Nevertheless, you can try to use a `list(...)` to impose a copy. Otherwise, sorry, I can't see why the `IOError`...

Comment: thank-you.  If I use the line in question `foo1.append` verbatim as you posted: I get `NameError: name 'line' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  I figured that was the issue and tried the for loop.  Unfortunately I still get a memory error using the `foo.append` method. Thanks again though.

Comment: This solution is not aproppriate for such large data, if it take 11 min to complete one round...

Answer (score 0):

This is untested. Note that it's probably in-efficient (and may not even be allowed) to attempt to have 4,000 filehandles open at once, so the file at a time approach is the most practical. Below uses a `defaultdict` which allows for mis-matching numbers of rows in each file, but still enables summing of overlapping row numbers.

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import defaultdict
from glob import iglob

def sum_file(filename, dd):
    file_total = 0.0
    with gzip.open(filename) as fin:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(islice(fin, 6, None)): # skip headers
            row_total = map(float, line.split())                
            dd[lineno] += row_total
            file_total += row_total
    return file_total


dd = defaultdict(float)
for filename in iglob('foo*.asc.gz'):
    print 'processed', filename, 'which had a total of', sum_file(filename, dd)

print 'There were', len(dd), 'rows in total'
for lineno in sorted(dd.keys()):
    print lineno, 'had a total of', dd[lineno]
```

Comment: yes your solution as well as Pierre's will be horribly slow for large amount of data. I would seriously use NumPy here.

Comment: @Oz123 I think we've interpreted the question differently. I've read it as there will be 1..n elements of sums where `n` is `max(number_of_rows)`, and where sum[n] = total of all columns of row[1] for file1..4000

Comment: the OP has added info, the size of his data is 1.3GB... I think that either way, 4000 lines or 4000 files, numpy will be faster, to sum all the float in each file and in all the files.

Comment: @Oz123: NumPy is definitely faster, provided you can fit two arrays in memory. If not, you're stuck.